# How to use UIImagePickerController with delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I added UIView (A Class) as a xib instance to ViewController.

I want to get image from UIImagePickerController of ViewController class by action (in A Class) and return it to A Class.

I wrote up the following codes.
However, I do not know how to return to A Class.

I made delegate to ViewController again but I abandoned it because I displayed various errors of delegate. [Un wrap error ..., just did not move anything ... etc].

```
// A Class
class A: CustomDelegate{
    var delegate001: PhotoLibraryDelegate!

    class func instance() -> A {
        return UINib(nibName: "A", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! A
    }

    @IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate001.selectPhoto() //I want photo in A Class XD. so make Delegate!!
    }
}

@objc protocol PhotoLibraryDelegate {
    func selectPhoto()
}

//ViewController Class
class ViewController: PhotoLibraryDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    let a = A.instance()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        a.delegate006 = self
    }

    func selectPhoto() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let pickerView = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerView.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            pickerView.delegate = self

            self.present(pickerView, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage // Yeah, I selected the image!!

        self.dismiss(animated: true)

        //... Wa!? I want to return "image" to A class. OMG.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is that you have already created the instance of A class. Now just directly assign the image to it.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage // Yeah, I selected the image!!

    a.imageView.image = image

    self.dismiss(animated: true)


}
```

Comment: It was a blind spot.
You are a genius. Thankyou :)